# Getting pushed files from sd card in ICS emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, snapshot

I've pushed some songs into the SD card in ICS Emulator. I then restarted the emulator by check marking the "wipe user data" option. Then the emulator opens with the music files in it. But i can't run my app in this mode. It shows:

```
ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has been saved for a different hardware configuration.
```

Then i quitted the emulator and again i launched it by checking the "launch from snapshot" option. But then the songs are not available in the music folder and i could not use this in my app.

What should i do to get the songs???